# reactivity disappears after the object was in the array

Tags: vue.js

Why, after passing through the reactive array, did the element's reactive property turn into a non-reactive one? Can you explain please.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref, Ref } from 'vue'
    
    interface Obj { 
      a: number;
      r: Ref<{s:string}>;
    }
    const obj: Obj = { a: 1, r: ref<string>({s:"one"}) }; //create an instance
    const valBeforeArr=obj.r.value  //the variable is displayed as it should be
    //put an instance in a reactive array, and get from it    
    const arr = ref<Obj[]>([]);
    arr.value.push(obj)  
    const valAfterArrRef=arr.value[0].r.value //reference value missing
    const valAfterArrNonRef=arr.value[0].r //and the original value is displayed normally
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <h2>valBeforeArr: {{ valBeforeArr }}</h2>
      <h2>valAfterArrRef: {{ valAfterArrRef ?? 'underfined' }}</h2>
      <h2>valAfterArrNonRef: {{ valAfterArrNonRef ?? 'underfined' }}</h2>
    </template>
```

[playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

As explained to me
Estus Flask, reactivity has not disappeared. You can verify this with the following code:

```
<template>
  <h2>valBeforeArr: {{ valBeforeArr }}</h2>
  <h2>valAfterArrRef: {{ valAfterArrRef ?? 'underfined' }}</h2>
  <h2>valAfterArrNonRef: {{ valAfterArrNonRef ?? 'underfined' }}</h2>
  <button @click="obj.r.value.s='seven'">updateBeforeArr</button>
  <button @click="arr[0].r.s='five'">updateAfterArr</button>
</template>
```

But in one case you have to access using ".value", and in the other, without it. This is inconvenient, given that the object, in accordance with the business logic, can either pass through the array or not. How to access a property universally?

Comment: The wording regarding reactive/non-reactive is incorrect. Nothing suggests that its non-reactive, it's just not a ref. arr is reactive, and nested refs in reactive objects are unwrapped.

Comment: In my opinion, it's still illogical behavior. There is an object, with reactive property. In accordance with business logic, it was placed in an array and taken out from there. (Or maybe it didn't fit.) But right from this moment (which might not have happened) I suddenly need to access the reactive property without using ".value"

Comment: I'd suggest to just avoid scenarios with surprising transitions from non-reactive to reactive objects. obj could be reactive object from the start and wouldn't have such problem, `r` would be consistently unwrapped as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#access-in-reactive-objects) explains this:

> When a ref is accessed or mutated as a property of a reactive object,
> it automatically unwraps to the inner value so it behaves like a
> normal property
>
> <...>
>
> Ref unwrapping only happens when nested inside a reactive Object.
> There is no unwrapping performed when the ref is accessed from an
> Array or a native collection type like Map

Since `ref` is deeply reactive, `arr.value` elements are reactive objects, and refs in `obj` properties are unwrapped when it's added to the array and becomes reactive.

`shallowRef` can be used in order to avoid unwrapping in nested refs.